# Jetty connections in CLOSE_WAIT are not closed

Tags: java, http, tcp, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

Jetty connections in CLOSE_WAIT are not getting closed.
Embedded jetty(9.4.11) is used with Glassfish for container & with dependency injection. Ngnix load balancer is forwarding request to jetty acting as a client. At Ngnix server(Client) the jetty TCP request/connection is going in FIN_WAIT2 state and then finally getting closed however on jetty(Server) connection are going in close_wait forever and not getting closed.

Any possible solution or configuration change to resolve it?

Reference: Jetty open issue link.
[Jetty-9.2 connections in CLOSE_WAIT are not closed](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/2169)

Http configuration(jetty.xml):

```
<New id="httpConfig" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration">
    <Set name="secureScheme">http</Set>
    <Set name="securePort"><Property name="jetty.secure.port" default="8443" /></Set>
    <Set name="outputBufferSize"><Property name="jetty.output.buffer.size" default="32768" /></Set>
    <Set name="outputAggregationSize"><Property name="jetty.output.aggregation.size" default="8192" /></Set>
    <Set name="requestHeaderSize"><Property name="jetty.request.header.size" default="8192" /></Set>
    <Set name="responseHeaderSize"><Property name="jetty.response.header.size" default="8192" /></Set>
    <Set name="sendServerVersion"><Property name="jetty.send.server.version" default="false" /></Set>
    <Set name="sendDateHeader"><Property name="jetty.send.date.header" default="false" /></Set>
    <Set name="headerCacheSize"><Property name="jetty.header.cache.size" default="512" /></Set>
    <Set name="delayDispatchUntilContent"><Property name="jetty.delayDispatchUntilContent" default="false"/></Set>
    <Set name="persistentConnectionsEnabled"><Property name="jetty.persistentConnectionsEnabled" default="false"/>false</Set>
    <Call name="addCustomizer">
        <Arg><New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ForwardedRequestCustomizer"/></Arg>
    </Call>
</New>

<Call id="httpsConnector" name="addConnector">
    <Arg>
        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
            <Arg name="server"><Ref refid="Server" /></Arg>
            <Arg name="acceptors" type="int"><Property name="ssl.acceptors" default="5"/></Arg>
            <Arg name="selectors" type="int"><Property name="ssl.selectors" default="0"/></Arg>
            <Arg name="factories">
                <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ConnectionFactory">         
                    <Item>
                        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnectionFactory">
                            <Arg name="config"><Ref refid="httpConfig"/></Arg>
                        </New>
                    </Item>
                </Array>
            </Arg> 
            <Set name="host"><Property name="jetty.host" /></Set>
            <Set name="port"><Property name="http.port" default="8443" /></Set>
            <Set name="idleTimeout"><Property name="https.timeout" default="30000"/></Set>
            <Set name="acceptorPriorityDelta"><Property name="ssl.acceptorPriorityDelta" default="0"/></Set>
            <Set name="acceptQueueSize"><Property name="https.acceptQueueSize" default="150"/></Set>
        </New>
    </Arg>
</Call>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Too many Close_wait in jetty 9.0.3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23644090/5221149)

Comment: OP updated old issue at https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/2169

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By analysing thread dump I figured out application threads are going in waiting state ( java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)) causing total lockup. Other library used by the application deployed in Jetty cause the thread wait not jetty.